# Проблема с загрузкой файлов в asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, пытаюсь сделать загрузку файлов на сервер. Если я загружаю файл размером 13mb, то через несколько секунд действие переходит к методу действия. Если я загружаю файл 30mb, то идет ожидание, и через 4.4 минуты запрос переходит в статус failed, в чем может быть проблема? таймауты прописывал в веб конфиге, не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в `web.config` такие настройки:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
</system.web>
```